# Not able to use Read Product API published by Salesforce CPQ to read more than 31 products

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am using Read Product API in order to read the Product Model and add Products to the Quote Line ,but the Read Product API is not able to read more than 31 products ,which results in adding only 31 products to the final Quote Line.

Can anyone please  tel me what is alternative way to add more Products to the Quote Lines through API?

Thanks in advance.

Link to information on ( Read Product API )- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.cpq_dev_api.meta/cpq_dev_api/cpq_api_read_product.htm

CODE

```
public class TestReadProduct {
Public static integer ReadProductsBulk(){


List<ProductModel>  Result = new List<ProductModel>();

    for(pricebookentry Prod:[select  Product2id,pricebook2id from pricebookentry where pricebook2id='01s6F00000GZ4OuQAL' ]){

        ProductModel Current = new ProductModel();

        Current = Current.readProduct(Prod.Product2id,Prod.pricebook2id,'USD');


            result.add(current);
        }

        return Result.size();
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is explicitly limiting the results `[select  Product2id,pricebook2id from pricebookentry where pricebook2id='01s6F00000GZ4OuQAL'  limit 32]` note the `limit 32` at the end. If you remove that you should be good to go.

Comment: I have updated the question,it is restricting me at 32 products that is why i had put the limit.